# Is it possible to use like and against in the same sql query?

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a search engine where the user starts typing a short word, search for it with LIKE %a% and use MATCH AGAINST ('aaaaa aaaaa ') when the word is bigger or there are multiple words

I have tried to join them with OR but I get an error

```
$search= "user search";

$data = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST('$search' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)");
```

Comment: *"but I get an error"* - Have you tried reading the error message?  What does it tell you?

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL Injection, you should use prepared statements and parameterized queries instead. Also, you only need the first `WHERE`.

Comment: David That: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool in /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/wooddocu3/php/search_bar.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/wooddocu3/inc/header.php(102): require_once() #1 /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/wooddocu3/index.php(15): include('/storage/emulat...') #2 {main} thrown in /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/wooddocu3/php/search_bar.php on line 16

Comment: @Table: There is no call to `fetchAll()` in the code shown.  As for whatever code you're not showing us... If you search that exact error message on your favorite search engine or here on Stack Overflow then you will find many duplicates for the same error.  In general it means that the query is failing but the code is assuming success and trying to use the result of a failed query.  You need to get the error message for the failed query.  Which can generally be done manually in your data access code, or potentially configured to throw an exception when it occurs.

Comment: GrumpyCrouton you can put your comment as an answer, your comment helped me

Answer (score -3):

You are missing a quote mark after your first search keyword. `'%$search%` should be `'%$search%'`.

Comment: Not my downvote, but in general it's frowned upon to answer questions where the problem is just a typo.  The question should simply be deleted in such cases as it serves no purpose to future readers.  (In this case the OP has also changed the code, rendering the original question and any answers moot.  A separate problem likely still exists, but hasn't been clarified.)

Comment: @David Thank you. I should have known better.